# How can i make a ggplot bar chart of one level of a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar graph of one level of a categorical variable. However, I am stuck at how to code ggplot2 properly so i can parse out the level. Here is my code below.

```
     head (Re_Space_wo2)

Re_Space_wo2
      Remain Gender NM1_SpacePump      Freq        Prop
1       3      2             0         230580.383  0.247448980
2       3      2             1         166398.214  0.178571429
3       3      1             0         118855.867  0.127551020
4       2      2             0          99838.929  0.107142857
5       4      2             0          80821.990  0.086734694
6       3      1             1          61805.051  0.06632653
```

I would like to graph to show results for only the following variables and levels. Remain, all levels. Gender only level 2, and NM1_SpacePump, all levels. I would like to keep the Freq and Prop columns as well. Could someone point me in the right direction?

I can make the bar chart for both genders. However, I would like to make a bar chart that only shows data for gender = 2 since i think this issues pertaining mainly to women (pumping breast milk).

[image]

It's only been about a month since I started exploring ggplot2. All help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide some raw data that we can easily copy/paste to solve your problem. Offhand, I'd say you need to calculate the percentages in your data frame before creating the plot. Also, I don't understand why you're using `coord_flip()` if you want the Frequency variable on the y axis.

Comment: @Phil good point. i knew I forgot something. Let me edit the question and add in the reproducible data. I use coord_flip to have a horizontal bar graph.

Comment: Ideally, post your data in a better copyable format - e.g. dput(your data) , or if this is too long - dput (head(your data)). Or create dummy data. Also, at least to me, it's not entirely clear what you actually want to achieve... Could you possible visualise your desired output?

Comment: @Tjebo i added data. Hopefully, this will clear up any confusion.

Comment: filter your data for women , e.g. `Re_Space_wo2[Re_Space_wo2$Gender == 2,]`